# Passing a ruby collection in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to pass a ruby collection to a javascript array to use in my calender plugin. I have an events array in javascript and I would like to use the attributes of each record in my ruby collection for the javascript array.

My Javascript:

```
calendar =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
                right: 'prev,next today'
            },
            events: [{
                    title: 'Event One',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                 },
                  {
                    title: 'Event two',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                 }, ...]
```

So with `events`, I would like to iterate through my @rubyevents collection in ruby, extract attributes of each record and use them in that javascript object. Something like this:

```
      events: function() {
         events = []
         <% @rubyevents.each do |r| %>
           e  = new Event();
           e[title] =  function() { return <%= r.name %> }...
           e[start] = function()  { return <%= r.date %> }
 
            events.push(e)
         <% end %>

         return events
        }
```

then return this array `events` as javascript with the ruby values. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Controller
...
@rubyevents = RubyEvent.all
...


//View
..
...
<%= javascript_tag do -%>
  var allEvents = '<%= @rubyevents.to_json.html_safe %>'
  
  events: function() {
   return JSON.parse(allEvents);
  }
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Would the date attribute be parsed this way? Can json handle date objects?

Comment: The date string will not be converted to the `Date` javascript object. You need to parse/create date manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions:

1. use gem `gon`:
   Gon can copy ruby data to JS directly.
   More information can be found on its github page: https://github.com/gazay/gon

```rb
# in rails controller
gon.events = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]
```

```js
// in js
console.log(gon.events)
// => [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]
```

2. render the ruby variables as JSON string and put it into data-*
   This is in fact the same approach as the `gon` but without the gem help.

```html
<div id="ruby-variables" data-variables="<%= [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}].to_json %>">
</div>
```

```js
const json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("ruby-variables").dataset.variables)
console.log(json)
// => [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}]
```

In fact, the principle of copying ruby data to JS is to render the data in the DOM first, then parse it from the JS side. `gon` use the same idea, too